# How to run cron.php in magento in fixed time interval

Tags: api, magento-1.7, cron

I have setup an API in Magento that fetches product information from third party and add them in product list in admin.

For this I have made a custom module and also setup crontab in its config.xml and set it to every 10 minutes.

API is working well and it adds product in admin product list.

I am getting problem in running **cron.php** which schedules all cron jobs in magento. 
I have to run it manually each time.

I want to run it automatically after a time interval. 
How is it possible..?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule cron.php from your admin panel.Go to 
System->configuration->System->Cron (Scheduled Tasks) - all the times are in minutes.

Set the Generate Schedules Every option to 10 and save the configuration.

If this does not work and you have the ssh server access then you can schedule cron.php in following way:
1-type "crontab -e" command.this will open the cron scheduler.
2. copy paste this line */15 * * * * path to magendo directory/cron.sh
3. save the file ESC+:+w+q.

Comment: Thank for answer @Ankur. I have setup cron section from admin panel in magento as you told me but still it is not running automatically.
I am doing it on my localhost.

Comment: On localhost,if you are on linux system then you can do that by manually creating entry in crontab. command:- sudo vi /etc/crontab and follow step 2.If you are window machine then search for how to setup cron in windows.

Comment: I am using windows server and xampp.